# MySQL regexp matching issue

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to match the following strings

```
'Brown & Brown' 'Brown and Brown' 'Brown&Brown' 'B & B' 'B and B' 'B&B'
```

I can get

```
'Brown & '
```

to match using

```
SELECT 'Brown & ' REGEXP '^(b|brown)[:space:]*(and|[.ampersand.])[:space:]*'
```

But when I try

```
SELECT 'Brown & Brown' REGEXP '^(b|brown)[:space:]*(and|[.ampersand.])[:space:]*(b|brown)'
```

or

```
SELECT 'Brown & Brown' REGEXP '^(b|brown)[:space:]*(and|[.ampersand.])[:space:]*(b|brown)$'
```

it won't match. What am I doing wrong with that last segment?

Comment: Indeed It only matters when you use the binary mode.

Comment: Are you sure you can match with the first regex? All `[:space:]` must be put into character classes like `[[:space:]]`. The [`^(b|brown)[[:space:]]*(and|[&])[[:space:]]*(b|brown)$`](https://regex101.com/r/xQ7jW8/1) seems working.

Comment: The strange thing is that `SELECT 'Brown & ' REGEXP '^(b|brown)[:space:]*(and|[.ampersand.])[:space:]*'` returns 1 when `SELECT '&' REGEXP '[.ampersand.]'` returns 0 and `SELECT '&' REGEXP '[[.ampersand.]]'` returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
SELECT 'Brown & Brown' REGEXP '^(b|brown)[[:space:]]*(and|[[.ampersand.]])[[:space:]]*(b|brown)$'
```

Special character classes must be put in doubled square brackets, e.g. `[[:space:]]` instead of `[:space:]`.

---

The reason why `SELECT 'Brown & ' REGEXP '^(b|brown)[:space:]*(and|[.ampersand.])[:space:]*';` worked:

- `[:space:]` was treated as a character class which contained characters `:, s, p, a, c, e`.
- `[.ampersand.]` was treated as a character class which contained characters `., a, m, p, e, r, s, a, n, d`.
- You allowed zero repetitions for these character classes (`*` quantifier), so the actually matched string was the first `Br`.
- It matched as follows: match start of the string, then `(b|brown)` matched `B`, `[:space:]*` matched empty string, `(and|[.ampersand.])` matched `r` (it's among the chars in `[.ampersand]` character class), then `[:space:]*` matched empty string.

Comment: Good job! `<°)))))))))))>`